# Simple regex - ignoring certain characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to use the `match` method with an argument of a regex to select a valid phone number, by definition, any string with nine digits.

For example:

- 9347584987 is valid,
- (456)322-3456 is valid,
- (324)5688890 is valid.

But

- (340)HelloWorld is NOT valid and
- 456748 is NOT valid.

So far, I'm able to use `\d{9}` to select the example string of 9 digit characters in a row, but I'm not sure how to specifically ignore any character, such as '**-**' or '**(**' or '**)**' in the middle of the sequence.

What kind of Regex could I use here?

Comment: try https://regex101.com/. Check the bottom right panel: "quick reference"

Comment: The easiest way is to remove those punctuation characters beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
nums=['9347584987','(456)322-3456','(324)5688890','(340)HelloWorld', '456748 is NOT valid']
```

You can split on a NON digit and rejoin to remove non digits:

```
> nums.map {|s| s.split(/\D/).join}
["9347584987", "4563223456", "3245688890", "340", "456748"]
```

Then filter on the length:

```
> nums.map {|s| s.split(/\D/).join}.select {|s| s.length==10}
["9347584987", "4563223456", "3245688890"]
```

Or, you can grab a group of numbers that look 'phony numbery' by using a regex to grab digits and common delimiters:

```
> nums.map {|s| s[/[\d\-()]+/]}
["9347584987", "(456)322-3456", "(324)5688890", "(340)", "456748"]
```

And then process that list as above.

That would delineate:

```
> '123 is NOT a valid area code for 456-7890'[/[\d\-()]+/]
=> "123"                               # no match
```

vs

```
> '123 is NOT a valid area code for 456-7890'.split(/\D/).join
=> "1234567890"                        # match
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using one regular expression for each valid pattern rather than constructing a single regex. It would be easier to test and debug, and easier to maintain the code. If, for example, `"123-456-7890"` or `123-456-7890 x231"` were in future deemed valid numbers, one need only add a single, simple regex for each to the array `VALID_PATTERS` below.

```
VALID_PATTERS = [/\A\d{10}\z/, /\A\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}\z/, /\A\(\d{3}\)\d{7}\z/]

def valid?(str)
  VALID_PATTERS.any? { |r| str.match?(r) }
end

ph_nbrs = %w| 9347584987 (456)322-3456 (324)5688890 (340)HelloWorld 456748 |
ph_nbrs.each { |s| puts "#{s.ljust(15)} \#=> #{valid?(s)}" }
9347584987      #=> true
(456)322-3456   #=> true
(324)5688890    #=> true
(340)HelloWorld #=> false
456748          #=> false
```

[String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. There are many alternatives, including `str.match(r)` and `str =~ r`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"9347584987"      =~ /(?:\d.*){9}/ #=> 0
"(456)322-3456"   =~ /(?:\d.*){9}/ #=> 1
"(324)5688890"    =~ /(?:\d.*){9}/ #=> 1
"(340)HelloWorld" =~ /(?:\d.*){9}/ #=> nil
"456748"          =~ /(?:\d.*){9}/ #=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Pattern:  ([Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/NBsRa0tpB8))

```
^\(?\d{3}\)?\d{3}-?\d{4}$   # this makes the expected symbols optional
```

---

This pattern will ensure that an opening `(` at the start of the string is followed by 3 numbers the a closing `)`.

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})\d{3}-?\d{4}$
```

---

On principle, though, I agree with melpomene in advising that you remove all non-digital characters, test for 9 character length, then store/handle the phone numbers in a single/reliable/basic format.